# make footer disappear when scroll is active

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery mobile.

How can I make footer disappear while scroll is active?

When scrolling stops I want to show footer again.

HTML snippet looks like this:

```
<div id="footer" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-corners="false">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [See Test Page](http://jsbin.com/yapuf/3/edit)

```
var pageIsScrolling = (function(){
   var timer, body = $(document.body);
   return function(){
       clearTimeout(timer);
       timer = setTimeout(scrollEnd, 250);
       body .addClass('scrolling');
   }

   function scrollEnd(){
       timer = null;
       body.removeClass('scrolling');
   }
})();

$(window).on('scroll.scrolling', pageIsScrolling);
```

Now whenever you start scrolling, the body has the class `scrolling` and you can target that in your **CSS**, like so:

```
.scrolling > footer{ opacity:0; }
```

or even add transition for your footer so it would look smoother.
(I'm pretty sure this should also work with jQuery mobile)

---

### notes:

- I could work directly on the `footer` element from javascript, but I believe working with general state classes is a better way to change states across an application, and then you can derive from that whatever you want in your CSS, so, here, the desired state class was "scrolling".
- I am using custom event namespace here, which is a good practice
- using element caching (body)
- `scrollEnd` function is separated and isn't directly written inside the `setTimeout` for better readability.

Comment: I have updated my answer, since I forgot to write the `clearTimeout`, which is very important

Answer (score 2):

Use `$.scroll` to hide the footer whilst scrolling and `setTimeout` to show it again once scrolling stops:

```
var scrolling;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    clearTimeout(scrolling);//clear any existing timeout
    $("#footer").hide();
    scrolling = setTimeout(function(){$("#footer").show();},100);//set the timeout to hide the footer (will be cancelled if scrolling continues)
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c6uqdhjo/1/

Answer (score 1):

Use the jquery scroll event.

You can find information in the docs: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Something along the lines of (not tested!):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $("#footer").hide();
});
```